# Customize/modifiy prompt text of a class property in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, formbuilder

I have below field in my class

```
[Prompt("Please enter conference title/subject")]
public string confname { get; set; }
```

I want to modify text "Please enter conference title/subject" dynamically.
Actually, I want to pass URL along with prompt text, how to achieve this?

I have tried below code, but don't know how to pass modified text in promptattribute

```
public static IForm<ConferenceBooking> BuildForm()
{
     return new FormBuilder<ConferenceBooking>().Message("Tell me meeting details!")
     .Field(nameof(confname), prompt: new PromptAttribute("please enter confname"))
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a parameter to the BuildForm() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SetDefine(delegate)` to dynamically change the attributes of a field. The delegate has two parameters: the state of the form and the field it's binded too. The delegate should always return true.

Here is an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleForm
{
    public string Name;

    [Numeric(1, 5)]
    [Prompt("Your experience with the form")]
    public float? Rating;

    public static IForm<SimpleForm> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<SimpleForm>()
                .Field(nameof(Rating))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<SimpleForm>(nameof(Name))
                    .SetDefine(DefinitionMethod))
                .Build();
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DefinitionMethod(SimpleForm state, Field<SimpleForm> field)
    {
        field.SetPrompt(new PromptAttribute($"You chose a rating of {state.Rating}. What is your name?."));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it's working but DefinitionMethod is getting called for the Field "Rating" also, it should get called only for "Name" field right??

Comment: Yeah but if I'm not mistake formflow will execute the delegate every time it builds. And it builds every time there is new user input.

Comment: e.g. If I write .Field(nameof(Rating), validate : ValidateRating) then delegate ValidateRating will execute only once that is for Rating,it will not be invoked for other fields.

Comment: I think this is just a behavior of the builder.